# $f\in E \mapsto \underset{{x\in[0,1]}}\sup f(x)$ continuous

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

> Let $E=(\mathcal{C}[0,1],\Vert f\Vert_{\infty})$ and $x\in [0,1].$ 
>   Denote $\phi: f\in E \mapsto \underset{{x\in[0,1]}}\sup f(x)\in \Bbb{R}.$
>
> I would like to prove that $\phi$ is continuous.

It means that $\forall\varepsilon>0\exists \eta>0\forall \tilde{f}\in E, \Vert f-\tilde{f} \Vert_{\infty}<\eta\implies\vert \phi(f)- \phi(\tilde{f})\vert<\varepsilon.$

$1)$ I have the following inequality $\vert \phi(f)-\phi(\tilde{f})\vert\le\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}+\Vert \tilde{f}\Vert_{\infty}$ but it's useless.

$2)$ I tried using sequential characterization but that does not seem like a better idea

Comment: This is just the reverse triangle inequality: $$\big \lvert \| u \| - \| v \| \big \rvert \le \| u - v\|$$ for any $u,v$ in a normed vector space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general we have: $$\sup_{x\in[0,1]} (f(x) + g(x)) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} f(x) + \sup_{x\in[0,1]} g(x)$$

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ and $\|f - \tilde{f}\|_\infty < \varepsilon$.

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) = \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\left((f(x) - \tilde{f}(x)) + \tilde{f}(x)\right) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} (f(x) - \tilde{f}(x)) +\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\tilde{f}(x)$$

In particular we have

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) - \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\tilde{f}(x) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} (f(x) - \tilde{f}(x)) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f(x) - \tilde{f}(x)| =\|f - \tilde{f}\|_\infty$$

Similarly we obtain

$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}\tilde{f}(x) - \sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} (\tilde{f}(x) - f(x)) \le \sup_{x\in[0,1]} |\tilde{f}(x) - f(x)| =\|f - \tilde{f}\|_\infty$$

Hence,

$$\left|\phi(f) - \phi(\tilde{f})\right| = \left|\sup_{x\in[0,1]}f(x) - \sup_{x\in[0,1]}\tilde{f}(x)\right| \le \|f - \tilde{f}\|_\infty < \varepsilon$$

So $\phi$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I write $||*|| $ instead of ||*||_{\infty}.

Let $c>0$. From $||f-g||<c$ it follows that $-c <f(x)-g(x)<c$ for all $x \in [0,1]$, hence

$f(x)<g(x)+c$ for all $x \in [0,1]$,

which gives $f(x)< \phi(g)+c$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and therefore $\phi(f) \le \phi(g)+c$.

Conclusion: $\phi(f)-\phi(g) \le c$.

In the same way we get  $\phi(g)-\phi(f)\le c$.

Thus we have shown: if  $||f-g||<c$ , then $|\phi(f)-\phi(g)|\le c$.